# How to get all dates between every intervals of start and end dates using c#

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I need to calculate the number of working dates excluding public holidays between every start and stop intervals. My application has a toggle button for start and stop. I had success with getting the number of dates between the first start date and the last stop date, but I need to remove the intervals between every stop and start date also. Any help will Appreciate.

I had created this method for calculating number of days:

```
  public int ElapseDays(string caseNo )
        {
            int count = 0;
            int weekEndsCount;
            Boolean excludeWeekends = true;

            using (var db = new EMSDEntities())
            {
                var q = (from a in db.SY_HOLIDAYS
                         orderby a.HLD_DATE
                         select new HolidayListViewModel
                         {
                            HolidayDate = a.HLD_DATE,

                         }).ToList();

                var startDate = DateTime.Parse("01/07/2019"); 
                var StopDate = DateTime.Parse("08/07/2019"); 

                for (DateTime index = startDate; index < StopDate; index = index.AddDays(1))
                {
                    if (excludeWeekends && index.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && index.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                    {
                        bool excluded = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < q.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (index.Date.CompareTo(q[i].HolidayDate) == 0)
                            {
                                excluded = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!excluded)
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                weekEndsCount = count;

            }


            return weekEndsCount;
        }
```

This gives me o/p : 6, After removing saturday and sunday

Expected Result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>start_date</th>
    <th>end_date</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01/07/2019</td>
    <td>03/07/2019</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>05/07/2019</td>
    <td>08/07/2019</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Expected o/p: 5

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. E.g. why 03/08/2019(Sunday) is expected date but 02/08/2019(Friday) isn't? Btw your `startDate` and `StopDate` variables are already dates: it's not needed to call `Convert.ToDateTime`. Also instead of looping through you holidays manually it's better to use `.Any` LINQ method.

Comment: I mistakenly put month as 8 instead of 7. changed it